# Sync two sheets regarding row insertion/deletion

Tags: excel

Is there a way to link two sheets in Excel in a way that I can have the first three columns synced between them (one way is sufficient) and at the same time have row insertion and deletion synced (one way is also sufficient here)?

For instance, I want the contents of columns A,B,C from Sheet1 copied to columns A,B,C of Sheet2 and when I delete a row in Sheet1 I want the whole row deleted in Sheet2 as well. Same thing for a row insertion.

Comment: Yes, there is. You write a macro. Perhaps have a go and, if you get stuck, edit the question with your code.

Comment: I was hoping there is a more elegant way to do this. To be more specific: I am afraid that one of the users might have macros disabled and will corrupt the whole sheet in the process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to get past the reference error. You will need to have at least one reference cell locked. I'm assuming that the column headers do not change

Here's how I would do it if it was `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` and row 1 is fixed

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,ROW()-1,)
```

the offset function can be used as an array or individual cell function.
I'm only using the first three arguments.

This is the syntax

```
OFFSET(reference, rows, cols, [height], [width])
```

I'm using the row function `ROW()` to return the row number and offset from the reference by ROW()-1

This should solve your issue as long as the reference is not deleted

Comment: That copies the content of the column but it does not seem to propagate row insertions or deletions to the rest of Sheet2.

Comment: Do you mean that there are some cells which have a zero at the end when the rows get deleted?

Comment: Both Sheet1 and Sheet2 are supposed to have additional columns. I want to have column A,B,C from Sheet 2 refer to the same columns of Sheet1. However for each row there will be additional information in additional columns. When deleting a row in Sheet1, I want the whole row in Sheet2 to be deleted. Your solution, however, does not delete the row in Sheet2, but merely the line in the columns that are synced.

Comment: @Rocreex ah gotcha. How about you create a hidden sheet for sheet 2 and do a lookup based on the other rows using the other three columns referenced using offset?

Comment: But then I have the same problem in the hidden sheet? Or how do you want to do the lookup?

Comment: chain the three columns `=A1&B1&C1` in column D on the hidden sheet and use `=vlookup(A1&B1&C1,range,colnum,false)` on the sheet visible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160637/discussion-between-rocreex-and-usernamenotfound).